# To find $p$ such that max/min of $(\sin p+\cos p)^{10}$ occurs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

To find max/min of $(\sin p+\cos p)^{10}$. I have to find value of $p$ such that the expression is max/min. I tried to manipulate expression so as to get rid of at least $\sin$ or $\cos$. Then I can put what is left over equals to $1$ to get the maximum. But I'm unable to do that.

Comment: Hint: $\sin p+\cos p=\sqrt{2}\sin(p+\pi/4)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\sin p+\cos p=\sqrt{2}\sin\left(p+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

$(\sin p + \cos p)^{10} = (\sin^2 p + 2\sin p\cos p + \cos^2 p)^5 = (1+\sin 2p)^5$

Function $x\mapsto (1+x)^5$ is monotone increasing, thus, extremes of $(1+\sin 2p)^5$ are the same as extremes of $\sin 2p$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be this
\begin{aligned}
(\sin p + \cos p)^{10} &= (\sin p + \cos p)^{2\times5}\\
&=(\sin^2p+\cos^2p+2\sin p\cos p)^5\\
&=(1+\sin{2p})^5
\end{aligned}
Since $-1\leq \sin{2p}\leq 1$ then $$0\leq(1+\sin{2p})^5=(\sin p + \cos p)^{10}\leq32$$ where $p=-\pi/4$ and $p=\pi/4$ correspond to the minimum and maximum, respectively, though not unique.